# Using join on a dictionary of dataframes by datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of dataframes which have two columns 'Time' (datetimeformat) and another column which is different for each dataframe.  The Time/Value entries are variable.

I want to join all of the dataframes to a master time dataframe which has 1 minute increments for the entire time range using the 'Time' value as a key.

`df_man_data` is the master time dataframe.  It looks like:

```
    Time
0   2019-01-01 13:44:00
1   2019-01-01 13:45:00
2   2019-01-01 13:46:00

531498  2020-01-05 16:02:00
531499  2020-01-05 16:03:00
531500  2020-01-05 16:04:00
531501  2020-01-05 16:05:00
```

one of the dictionary dataframes looks like this:

```
    Time                V-106A_TAP_7
0   2019-01-05 09:39:00 22.0
1   2019-01-07 09:42:00 30.0
2   2019-02-06 08:58:00 8.0
3   2019-02-06 21:25:00 16.0

262 2020-02-11 09:00:00 32.0
263 2020-02-12 20:08:00 34.0
264 2020-02-13 09:34:00 2.0
```

I've tried this:

```
df_man_data = df_time

for tag in tags:
    df_man_data.join(df_dic[tag].set_index('Time'), on='Time', how='left')
```

but my `df_man_data` comes out with no extra columns

Comment: you need to assign it back, `join` is not an in-place transformation, ie `df_man_data = df_man_data.join(df_dic[tag].set_index('Time'), on='Time', how='left')`

Comment: YES! thank you. I can't tell you how long i sat staring at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for loop to

```
for tag in tags:
    df_man_data = df_man_data.join(df_dic[tag].set_index('Time'), on = 'Time',how = 'left')
```

.join() returns a new dataframe and assigning that new, joined dataframe to df_man_data each loop should capture all of your new columns of data iteratively.